# Detect selected block pattern from a specific Pattern category

Tags: block-editor

It is possible to detect when the Inserter panel is opened. It can be done using the following code snippet:

```js
wp.data.select( 'core/edit-post' ).isInserterOpened()
```

However, I am wondering if there is an event in `wp.data` that allows to detect if the user has selected a block pattern (via Patterns tab) from a specific category (for instance, the Query category).

**Use case**

I have a theme that has two templates: Default and Custom.

The Default template displays a page layout with the page title, content area and sidebar.

The Custom template displays a page layout with with content only.

Also, the theme has a special Pattern category named "Pages". This category contains pre-made page layouts.

By default, WordPress displays (sets) Default template as initial template of the page.

My goal is to detect when user selects a block pattern from "Pages" category, and change template from Default to Custom in the editor automatically.

Comment: what are you trying to do that requires this? Can you add any context? Note that once a pattern is used it becomes the blocks the pattern contains, the pattern itself doesn't exist in the content

Comment: Thank you for a suggestion, Tom. I have added more context to my question.